# Get first object from array using getJSON (JQuery) and for.each

Tags: javascript, foreach, getjson

Right now, I am getting multiple values listed because I'm appending the objects from the for each loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=51.522035&lon=-0.105732",function(result){

  $.each(result.weather, function(i,item){
  $('#testfield').append('<p>' + item.main + '</p>');
  });

});
});
```

I only want to have the 1st object from the JSON output into testfield div, not all of it.

I tried this but it didn't work

```
     $.each(result.weather, function(i,item[0]){
```

FYI: Sometimes, the weather feed provides more than 1 weather.main. Sometimes, only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the first element, then simply do that *instead* of looping:

```
$('#testfield').append('<p>' + result.weather[0].main + '</p>');
//                                           ^^^
//                          access the first element in result.weather
```